# How to prevent certain warning on IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, intellij-14

What's the correct way to prevent warnings on IntelliJ, for example this code:

[image: warning]

the `.children_str` gives warning `Unresolved variable children_str`. The `children_str` property is a `string`, and `row` is an `Object`.

Normally I would add a namespace (I don't know what is it, but it removes those warnings):

[image: after adding namespace]

But then another warning appeared `Unresolved function or method split()`

What's the correct way to tell IntelliJ that `children_str` is a string to remove those warning message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The warning can be removed by assigning and adding `||` operator, for example:

```
row.children_str = row.children_str || '';
```

Comment: It's not a suppress, it's just a trick to twist static analyzer.

Comment: but this answers the question: "What's the correct way to tell IntelliJ that `children_str` is a string to remove those warning message?"

Comment: or do you have any other solution rather than disables entire inspection.. the final target is make my code correct according to IntelliJ and still give the same output when executed..

Comment: You can suppress inspection per method. Your solution is making code worse. You shouldn't try to twist inspections.

Answer (score 4):

You can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to see Idea's way to resolve this warning. If there are none, you can always disable `JavaScript Inspections`. There are two ways:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then click right arrow and select `Disable Inspection`
- Go to `File -> Settings -> Inspections` and find `JavaScript` inspections options. There you can disable any inspections that annoy you, like `Unresolved JavaScript function` or `Unresolved JavaScript variable`

Comment: no, the shortcut key, I never know about it.. XD (previously I always use mouse)